# Prevent expanded notification view

Tags: android-notifications, android-remoteview

I have this code to style my notification:

```
    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.notification);

    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notification);
    mBuilder.setCustomContentView(remoteViews);
    mBuilder.setOngoing(true);
    mBuilder.setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_PROGRESS);
    mBuilder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
    mBuilder.setShowWhen(false);
    mBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle());
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
```

As you can see I haven't defined an expanded view for the notification by calling `mBuilder.setCustomBigContentView()`. Nevertheless the notification is showing with a arrow pointing up as if my notification was expanded. How can I prevent that arrow from showing?

Answer (score 1):

Remove line

```
mBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle());
```

Comment: For me this didn't work

Answer (score 0):

my personal workaround is this

```
mBuilder.setContentView(remoteViews);
mBuilder.setCustomBigContentView(remoteViews);
```

i.e. send the same remoteViews in big content view that are in the small notifucation view